# Filtering Results in a SQL view

Tags: sql, view

I have a view that has thousands of records of financial transactions that are pulled from a SAP view. This view is great for all transaction types (invoices, credits, purchase orders) except for payments. This is due to a payment record being duplicated for the number of invoices that it references. Example below:

```
TransactionMstID    SupplierID  DebtorID    TransactionDate TransactionSubmissionDate   TransactionRef  TransactionValue    TransactionStatus   CurrencyType    TransactionRelatedDocNumber
538685  46  22  2016-05-03  2018-08-02  50356   123578.78   Current ZAR 382
538689  46  22  2016-05-03  2018-08-02  50356   123578.78   Current ZAR 386
```

The problem is that there may be 50 records that the payment relates to (`TransactionRelatedDocNumber`) and I don't want to sum the duplicate `TransactionValue` records as that inflates the total figure. Is there a way to only select the first record that has the duplicated `TransactionRef` value?

I'm hoping there's a simple solution to this in order to keep the data in a view rather than moving over to a Stored Procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses `row_number()`:

```
select sum( . . . )
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by TransactionRef order by TransactionMstID) as seqnum
      from t
     )
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising, I've implemented most of it but get an `Invalid column name 'seqnum'` error. Any idea why this would happen?

Comment: @Daniel . . . That seems really strange.  It is defined in the subquery.

Comment: Seems to work on the view itself but not in a SQL query. Either way, you've been a massive help and I've learned a new SQL function, thank you!